# How do I pass through --program-prefix=PREFIX from configure to one of the child makefiles?

Tags: gnu, autoconf

Autoconf has gotten me stumped.

I have tried modifying the COMPILE in Makefile.in as follows

```
COMPILE = $(CC) $(DEFS) $(DEFAULT_INCLUDES) $(INCLUDES) $(AM_CPPFLAGS) \
        $(CPPFLAGS) $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -DFINALDIR=\"$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)\"
```

but my use of FINALDIR is undefined.  What is the proper way to do it?  In my defense the whole autoconf business is a rats nest of preprocessors hiding anything obvious.

Thanks in advance... sorry I am such a tool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to move that definition into `CPPFLAGS` or `AM_CPPFLAGS`; it's quite possible that something is running the C preprocessor only, without running the compiler, or at least running the compiler without using `${COMPILE}`.

Comment: acually i moved it to the cppflags for the binary itself in makefile.in

Comment: ahh so that compile macro really isn't used